# Geocoding with REST API gives different results from Here WeGo online map

Tags: here-api, geocode

I'm a student working on a navigation project using Here's REST APIs.

The question I'm asking pertains to discrepancies when searching for a location using the Geocoder REST API and the Here WeGo online map.

I am trying to perform forward geocoding using the search term "Kent Ridge MRT" via the Geocoder API to get the corresponding set of coordinates. This is a subway station located on my campus, which the National University of Singapore.

The following parameters are used

```
destination_input = "Kent Ridge MRT singapore"
country = "SGP"
gen = 9
```

These are placed in a dict called geocoding_params

```
geocoding_params = {"app_code": app_code, "app_id": app_id, "searchtext": destination_input,
"country": country, "gen": gen}
```

A GET request is then made using the requests library in Python 3.7.3, via

```
geocoding_data = requests.get(url = geocoding_base_url, params = geocoding_params)
```

Where `geocoding_base_url = "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json"`

The request gives me three possible locations, listed here in Lat/Lon: (1.30098, 103.77231), (1.29354, 103.77138) & (1.2935, 103.78102).

None of these are the actual coordinates of Kent Ridge MRT station (1.29364, 103.78466), which can be obtained when one types the exact same search terms using Here WeGo.

I am curious to know why such a difference exists and whether there is a way to get what I see in Here WeGo.

What I have tried as of now includes broadening the search field by removing `country` and `gen` parameters while keeping `searchtext = "Kent Ridge MRT singapore"`, but to no avail. The results match the three I have gotten above.

Answer (score 0):

The SearchAPI powering HereWeGo and GeocoderAPI are different services with different approaches and goals. The reason why you are not finding your place "Kent Ridge MRT"with GeocoderAPI is because GeocoderAPI does not support places.

The good news: both are unified as OpenSearch in the HERE Open Location Platform:
https://developer.here.com/products/open-location-platform

Check the Open Location Platform documentation at
https://openlocation.here.com/resources/documentation